# Fullcalendar : get clicked date

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar

I'm struggling with that. I'm trying to get the date of the clicked day on fullcalendar V5.

I've been digging in the **info.event** of the function and some other stuff, but all I can achieve is to get the start date of the event.

If I click on **test2** at this date "29", I want to get something like this : "2020-11-29"

[image]

Comment: This isn't possible. There are several questions in the past where people have asked the same thing and been told it isn't possible already.

Comment: I agree with that, but answers found were post a few year ago. Still in 2020 this isn't possible ?

Comment: Yes. And the reasons are the same - the events are overlaid on top of the calendar grid, not within the time cells, therefore there's no way to associate one specific area of an event with the time underneath it. Not all the answers are old, I remember someone asking it only a couple of months ago I think. Out of interest, why do you want to be able to do this anyway?

Comment: I've seen some new answer, but for V3 or V4, not V5. I need that because my client wanted to show all event of the day when he clicks on a event

Comment: For that they would be better to click on an empty space in the day, then it's easy. Or you can configure the calendar so that when you click on the day number in the month view, it takes you directly to the day view - again, that's easy to set up

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to do, but you know... orders are orders :) so, after a few conversation, we ended up by showing only the clicked event... But I guess it you be greate to add that feature, as complicated that could be... I saw people achieve that by getting coordinate of the click based on pageY and pageX... But doesn't sound stable !

Comment: No that's not stable at all, I wouldn't recommend it. You _could_ try requesting the feature, if it hasn't been requested already (see https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) but I suspect it will be impossible to implement internally in the fullCalendar code as well, for the same reason I've mentioned above. I could be wrong though - you can only ask the developers if it's possible.